# how to integrate laravel 5.1 with elasticsearch 2.1.1

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to integrate elasticsearch on laravel 5.1 
I have tested some packages but I couldn't use theme because I didn't find any sample code of how to index and query in controllers and how to index all records of a table in database

please give me a simple project of elasticsearch  in laravel 5.1
thanks

Comment: SO isn't the place to ask for us to point you in the direction of projects or tutorials, that is what Google is for. However, a quick search for you reveals this, which is quite detailed and explicit as to how to implement elasticsearch for Laravel http://www.fullstackstanley.com/read/simple-search-with-laravel-and-elasticsearch